# listview.setAdapter(myAdapter) not working with custom adapter code

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've made a custom ArrayAdapter which takes an array of Movie objects, and then places the movie's poster image into an imageview and the title into a textview. The Movie class's fields are seen here; it has standard getters and setters.

```
public class Movie {
    protected String id;
    protected String posterPath;
    protected String title;
```

Here is the custom ArrayAdapter constructor:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     *
     * @param context Current context used to inflate layout file
     * @param movies list of Movie objects that will be displayed in list
     */
    public MovieAdapter(Activity context, List<Movie> movies){
        super(context, 0, movies);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "adapter constructor");
        if(movies != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, movies.get(i).getTitle());
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the fragment OnCreateView code that calls the adapter:

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {
    //number of movies to be displayed
    private static final int ARG_NUM_MOVIES = 40;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MovieFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Movie> movieInfo;
    private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;


    public MovieFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView Start");
        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), movieInfo);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "listview creation");
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_movies);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "listview creation2");
        listView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        /*listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String
            }
        }*/
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "return statement");
        return rootView;
    }
```

Based on the logs, I've deduced that there is an error in setting my adapter to the listView, but I don't know what causes it. I've also demonstrated that the list in the custom Adapter is empty to begin with/null (if it isn't always).

Here are the error logs that lead up to the crash in my app:

```
06-02 15:47:47.276 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/MovieFragment: onCreateView Start
06-02 15:47:47.276 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/MovieAdapter: adapter constructor
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@1816532
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@7998283
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@7998283
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/MovieFragment: listview creation
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/MovieFragment: listview creation2
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-02 15:47:47.286 22311-22311/com.example.android.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.popularmovies, PID: 22311
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.popularmovies/com.example.android.popularmovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:508)
                                                                                       at com.example.android.popularmovies.MovieFragment.onCreateView(MovieFragment.java:54)
                                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
```

Comment: `movieInfo` is null when you set your `Adapter`. Initialize it first.

Comment: Before use of Movie object assign the movieInfo= new List<Movie>();

Comment: initialize by `List<Movie> movieInfo = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks Mike! I got something to pop up on my screen w/o crashing

Comment: You need to initialize and add some values to that array.

Answer (score 1):

movieInfo is just a reference which don't point to any object means it has null.

Please create the object of movieInfo like:

```
movieInfo = new ArrayList<>();
```

and give some value to it like:

```
movieInfo.add(new Movie("1","path one","ONE"));
movieInfo.add(new Movie("2","path two","TWO"));
movieInfo.add(new Movie("1","path three","THREE"));
movieInfo.add(new Movie("1","path four","FOUR"));
movieInfo.add(new Movie("1","path five","FIVE"));
```

and then set the adapter to list.